# How to load wp_editor using Jquery?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, wp-editor

I want to add WordPress editor dynamically using jquery in my custom plugin as follow:

```
 <?php

  $content = '';

  $editor_id = 'mycustomeditor';      

?>

 $('#container').append('<?php wp_editor( $content, $editor_id );?>');
```

I am getting error:

> SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
>
> ```
> ...-active"><link rel='stylesheet' id='editor-buttons-css'  href='http://localhost
> ```

I have also tried bellow code(here I have replaced single quotes to double quotes):

```
  <?php

     $content = '';

     $editor_id = 'mycustomeditor';      

  ?>

  $('#container').append("<?php wp_editor( $content, $editor_id );?>");
```

I am getting error:

> ```
>  SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list   
>
>
> $('#container').append("<div id="wp-mycustomeditor-wrap" class="wp-core-ui wp-ed...
> ```

If you have any solution please let me know.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

I know late answer. but it will help others. Try this jQuery plugin.

https://github.com/anteprimorac/js-wp-editor

you can use simple like below

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function (){

        jQuery('#container').wp_editor();

    });
```

Answer (score 2):

```
   add_action('init','my_wpEditOUPUTT');function my_wpEditOUPUTT(){
if (isset($_POST['Give_me_editorrr'])){
    wp_editor( '' , 'txtrID_'.$_POST['myNumber'], $settings = array( 'editor_class'=>'my_class',     'textarea_name'=>'named_'. $_POST['myNumber'],  'tinymce'=>true , 'media_buttons' => true , 'teeny' => false,));
    exit;   
}}

<div id="MyPlace"></div> <a href="javascript:myLoad();">Click to load</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
  startNumber = 1;
  function myLoad(){ alert('wait 1 sec');
  startNumber ++;
  $.post('./index.php', '&Give_me_editorrr=1&myNumber='+startNumber ,
    function(data,status){ 
        if (status == "success") {  
            document.getElementById('MyPlace').innerHTML += data; alert("Inserted!");   
            tinymce.init({ selector: 'txtrID_'+startNumber, theme:'modern',  skin:'lightgray'}); tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddEditor', false, 'txtrID_'+startNumber);
        }
});}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you are using single inverted comma here:

> `'<?php wp_editor( $content, $editor_id );?>'`

and here:

```
   $content = '';
   $editor_id = 'mycustomeditor';
```

Try with double inverted commas, and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

you nee comment internal  char (") and change wp_ by the_ to get string.

in php:

```
$editorCode = the_editor( $content, $editor_id );
```

in script replace:

```
$('#container').append("<?php echo str_replace('"', '\"', $editorCode); ?>");
```